Excel - Format Color/Width of a Specific Y Axis Value
I am trying to format a specific Y axis value (say, 5) in Excel to make it bold & change color to Red to show the threshold. Can you do that in Excel? I may be able to do that with a separate series, but can we get this without a separate series?
Here is what I am trying to achieve.
Thanks.


Create an extra column labeled "Threshold". Insert the desired value of the threshold for every row (5 in your example). Then use a combo chart to have columns for Series 1-3 and a line for the threshold column.

Thanks. But I do not want to create another data series, if possible.

Emmmmmm, how about inserting a line shape to the chart?

Yes. I can do that as well, but when I copy the graph, it does not "stay" with it.
